# Fedora grep Revocation date from crl

Tags: openssl, fedora

I need to retrieve a revocation date from a crl file, i have been given the Serial number. However i have no experience with fedora openssl.

I know how to get all files from the crl but not the specific files i want.

with the code:

```
openssl crl -in /home/admin/Downloads/UTN-USERFirst-Object.crl -inform DER -noout -text
```

this retrieves all files. probably also the one i need.
With the following code i can see the serial number

```
openssl crl -in /home/admin/Downloads/UTN-USERFirst-Object.crl -inform DER -noout -text | grep 0E991C92029B760A027CC64219482BC8
```

this returns only the serial number of the file i need and not the Revocation date.

How can i also retrieve the revocation date from this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. By putting -A 1 at the end of the code it returns more lines.
so the code has to be:

```
openssl crl -in /home/admin/Downloads/UTN-USERFirst-Object.crl -inform DER -noout -text | grep 0E991C92029B760A027CC64219482BC8 -A 1
```